# hostname -I platform independent?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, hostname

I am using `hostname -I` to list all of the IP addresses for a host. I then processes this list under the assumption that it is space delimited. Is this assumption valid in general? I see that the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) says that you shouldn't make assumptions about order, but can I assume that

- This command and option is available on all major distributions of linux
- The output produced by this command is always space delimited

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, at least not until you sufficiently limit "all major distributions of linux". Older versions don't have this option at all and e.g. the BSD/MacOS version is completely different.

Comment: What do you think about Ubuntu 12.04+, CentOS/RHEL 6/7 ?